# How to select an option from auto suggestions using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autosuggest, webdriverwait

I have these two options in custom dropdown - `British Indian Territory` and `India`. Using selenium sendKeys when I am entering "India", it is not able to enter India in the respective country field, since it is unable to differentiate between British 'India'n Territory and `India` values in the dropdown.

Link to the website:
https://www.westernunion.com/gb/en/send-money/app/register

```java
WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"countryOfBirthField\"]"));

country.clear();
country.sendKeys(" india ");
```

Comment: it will show both because both strings contain india. so  it will list  both but what exactly you want to do want to select india or want to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Among the two dropdown options as *British Indian Territory* and *India* to select **India** in the respective country field you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.westernunion.com/gb/en/send-money/app/register");
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#countryOfBirthField")));
          element.sendKeys("india");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope']//li/a[@title='India']/strong[text()='India']"))).click();
      }    
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: countryOfBirthIndia]

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach to achieve

driver.get("https://www.westernunion.com/gb/en/send-money/app/register");
dropdownstackoverflow=commonMethod.getWebelement(driver, bdropdownstackoverflow);
dropdownstackoverflow.sendKeys("India");

Robot r=new Robot();

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```